# Pydantic Model Structure for Largely Similar Objects?

Tags: python, json, pydantic

I wonder if anyone might have a suggestion for a better way to build up a Pydantic model for this case?

The data set I am working with (JSON) is mostly the same structure throughout, but with some differences only down at the lowest levels of the tree. ie:

```json
// data.json
{
    "FirstItem": {
        "Name": "first item",
        "Data": {
            "attr_1": "a",
            "attr_2": "b"
        }
    },
    "SecondItem": {
        "Name": "second item",
        "Data": {
            "attr_3": "d",
            "attr_4": "e"
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

So I am wondering, is there a suggested method for building a Pydantic model that uses a standard 'Item' (in this case, it would have 'Name' and 'Data'), but then change the 'Data' on a case-by-case basis?

I have a working example, but it feels quite verbose?

working example:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class FirstItemData(BaseModel):
    attr_1: str
    attr_2: str

class FirstItem(BaseModel):
    Name: str
    Data: FirstItemData # <--- The unique part

class SecondItemData(BaseModel):
    attr_3: str
    attr_4: str

class SecondItem(BaseModel):
    Name: str
    Data: SecondItemData

class Example(BaseModel):
    FirstItem: FirstItem
    SecondItem: SecondItem

o = Example.parse_file("data.json")
```

The above *does* work, but it feels like building the Item 'holder' each time (the part with 'Name' and 'Data') is redundant? Is there way to specify a generic 'container' structure, and then swap out the 'Data'"? Something like:

```py
class GenericContainer(BaseModel):
    Name: str
    Data: ????

class Example(BaseModel):
    FirstItem: GenericContainer(Data = FirstItemData)
    SecondItem: GenericContainer(Data = SecondItemData)
```

or something of that sort? In this case I have several dozen of these unique 'Items' (only unique in their 'Data' part) and it doesn't seem correct to create 2 classes for each one? Does it?

I do realize that using the type `Dict` in place of the detailed 'Data' does work to load in the data, but it comes in as a dict instead of an object, which is not ideal in this case.

any thoughts or suggestions are much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen [Generic Models](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#generic-models)?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment from Hernán Alarcón, i wanted to try and
i believe this should work. Perhaps it will usefull to someone.

```py
from pydantic.generics import BaseModel, GenericModel
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, Optional

class FirstItemData(BaseModel):
    attr_1: str
    attr_2: str
class SecondItemData(BaseModel):
    attr_3: str
    attr_4: str
TypeX = TypeVar('TypeX')
class GenericContainer(GenericModel, Generic[TypeX]):
    Name: str
    Data: TypeX
class ItemBag(BaseModel):
    FirstItem: Optional[GenericContainer[FirstItemData]]
    SecondItem: Optional[GenericContainer[SecondItemData]]

# some tests
one_bag = ItemBag(FirstItem = {"Name":"My first item", "Data":{"attr_1":"test1", "attr_2":"test2"}})
another_bag = ItemBag(FirstItem = {"Name":"My first item", "Data":{"attr_1":"test1", "attr_2":"test2"}}, SecondItem = {"Name":"My first item", "Data":{"attr_3":"test3", "attr_4":"test4"}})
# failing tests to slightly check validation
one_failing_bag = ItemBag(FirstItem = {"Name":"My first item", "Data":{"attr_3":"test1", "attr_42":"test2"}})
another_failing_bag = ItemBag(SecondItem = {"Name":"My second item", "Data":{"attr_3":"test3", "attr_42":"test2"}})

# the parsing way
parsed_bag = ItemBag.parse_obj({"FirstItem":{"Name":"My first item", "Data":{"attr_1":"test1", "attr_2":"test2"}}, "SecondItem": {"Name":"My first item", "Data":{"attr_3":"test3", "attr_4":"test4"}}})
```

So it works,
but i am not sure i'd choose genericity versus readability.